# dynamic form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form similar to the image attached below, how "add the question" can be done using javascript? and I am trying to use express(nodejs framework).

Now if user clicks add question option then a similar form could be attached multiple times.

```
<h1>Create</h1>
<div class="main">
<form action="/handle" method="post">
    
        
        <div class="option">
            <label for="topic">Topic</label>
            <input type="text" id="topic" name="topicname" required>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
    <label for="question">Enter your question:</label>
    <input type="text" id="question" name="questioninput" required>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
    <label for="option1">option 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="option1" name="option1input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="option">

    <label for="option2">option 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="option2" name="option2input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
    <label for="option3">option 3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="option3" name="option3input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
    <label for="option4">option 4:</label>
    <input type="text" id="option4" name="option4input" required>
        </div>
        <div>
    <button type="submit">Send your response</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

image representation:

[image: image representation]

Comment: Are you using any frontend framework as well, or you just using JS?

Comment: Where will you be storing those data?

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram Just using JS as I am just a beginner.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan MySQL database.